# Redis Lua script - how to pass array as argument to a Lua script in nodejs?

Tags: arrays, lua, redis

I am calling a Lua script from nodejs. I want to pass an array as argument. I am facing problem to parse that array in Lua.

Below is an example:

```
var script = 'local actorlist = ARGV[1] 
if #actorlist > 0 then
for i, k in ipairs(actorlist) do
   redis.call("ZADD","key", 1, k)
end
end';

client.eval(
     script, //lua source
     0,
     ['keyv1','keyv2']
     function(err, result) {
         console.log(err+'------------'+result);
     }
    );
```

It gives me this error:

> "ERR Error running script (call to f_b263a24560e4252cf018189a4c46c40ce7d1b21a): @user_script:1: user_script:1: bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' (table expected, got string)

Comment: What is the value of `ARGV[1]` suppose to be? How does it get its value? eg. is it a string containing comma separated list of actors?

Comment: According to https://redis.io/commands/eval, you should be using `ARGV` or `KEYS` called with `client.eval(script, 2, ...`

Comment: @greatwolf, ARGV[1] would be array of values like   ['keyv1','keyv2']

Comment: Not according to the error message. It sees a string, not an array.

Comment: Judging from this [issue](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/495), looks like js arrays turn into strings when passed into `eval`. Is there a reason for not unpacking the array first and passing them in as separate arguments?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just by using **ARGV**:

```
local actorlist = ARGV

for i, k in ipairs(actorlist) do
```

and pass arguments in console like this:

```
eval "_script_" 0 arg1 arg2 argN
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only pass in strings into Redis lua script.

If you need an array of values to be pass into Redis lua script, you can do this:

```
let script = `
if #ARVG > 0 then
    for i, k in ipairs(ARGV) do
       redis.call("ZADD","key", 1, k)
    end
end`;

client.eval(
     script, //lua source
     0,
     ...['keyv1','keyv2'],
     function(err, result) {
         console.log(err+'------------'+result);
     }
);
```

The key here is to pass `keyv1` and `keyv2` as a separate params when calling eval. (I am using es6 syntax here)